# android bluetooth pairing callback method

Tags: android, bluetooth

Can any one tell me the callback method the bellow code. Is there any other efficient code available for this purpose???

```
private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
        Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
        m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Exception: "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
}
```

For better clarification I added the full code. I want to do something on the pairing completion

```
public class BtScan extends AppCompatActivity {

Button bt;
ListView listView;
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
Set<BluetoothDevice> devicesArray;
IntentFilter filter;
BroadcastReceiver receiver;
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
ArrayList<String> pairedDevices;
ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_bluetooth_scan);

    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    btAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    if (!btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        turnOnBT();
    }

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Selected bt", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String tmp=prefs.getString("mac","");
    if(!tmp.equals("")){
        Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),BtIns.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("MAC",tmp);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else {
        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_bT_scan);
        bt.setTransformationMethod(null);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_listViewscan);



        newScan();

        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                newScan();
            }
        });


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (btAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                }

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Selected bt", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("mac", devices.get(i).getAddress());
                editor.commit();

                if (!listAdapter.getItem(i).contains("Paired")) {
                    try {
                        BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(i);
                        pairDevice(selectedDevice);
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        newScan();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                } else {
                    BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(i);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BtIns.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    intent.putExtra("MAC", selectedDevice.getAddress());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

private void newScan(){
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"New Scan Start",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

    listAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,0);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    btAdapter.startDiscovery();
}
private void getPairedDevices() {
    devicesArray = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(devicesArray.size()>0){
        for(BluetoothDevice device:devicesArray){
            pairedDevices.add(device.getName());

        }
    }
}

void turnOnBT(){
    Intent intent =new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivity(intent);
}

void init(){

    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String action = intent.getAction();

            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"new br: "+action,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){

                pairedDevices=new ArrayList<String>();
                getPairedDevices();
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Dev: "+device.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                devices.add(device);
                String s = "";
                for(int a = 0; a < pairedDevices.size(); a++){
                    if(device.getName().equals(pairedDevices.get(a))){
                        //append
                        s = "(Paired)";
                        break;
                    }
                }

                listAdapter.add(device.getName()+" "+s+" "+"\n"+device.getAddress());

            }
            else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
                if(btAdapter.getState() == btAdapter.STATE_OFF){
                    turnOnBT();
                }
            }


        }
    };
}

private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
        Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
        m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Exception: "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try {
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {

        init();

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED));
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED));
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));


        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Registration",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

    }
    catch (Exception e){}
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide more info. What are you trying to do? You are following some tutorial? Can you provide more code? What is the problem with the actual code?

Comment: I want to call a method after the pairing competition.

Comment: I edit the post with full code

Comment: From your code I can conclude that you need a callback after the BT connection was made. The Android Bluetooth tutorial has everything that you need: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: the matter of fact is that not only bluetooth but also the areas where permission require are changed and several documentation does not include them properly

Comment: Did you figure this out?? @SiddharthaSadhukhan

Comment: No, above procedure was the only procedure which I found.